# What's the best way to parse nested attributes in XML using Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, attributes, element

So I'm working within an xml file that basically has a nested array of elements with each element having a lot of nested attributes:

```
<Export land_name="tx">
<Area>
    <Location name="foo"
              square_feet="10,000"
              highway="I-35"/>
    <Location name="dog"
              square_feet="20,000"
              highway="I-45"/>
</Area>
</Export>
```

My goal is to parse out the attributes (square_feet, highway, name) and output them to a .csv file. I'm using XML::Simple but the more I've worked with it I think I'm using the wrong package. My main question is what is the best control structure to parse out the nested attributes? I keep getting caught up on referring to non-existent has references or array references. Here is the code I have so far:

```
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
my $in = "XML_in.xml";
my $xml = XML::Simple->new(KeyAttr => [], ForceArray => [Device], KeepRoot => 1 );
my $Inv = $xml->XMLin($in);
print $Inv->{Export}->{Area}->{Location}->[0]->{name};
```

If my code is in error, is it the incorrect usage of the `KeyAttr`, `ForceArra`y, or `keeproot`?

Comment: Yes, you are. Even the documentation says not to use it. :)

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a very good first question. :)

Comment: No such thing as nested attributes?!?

Answer (score 5):

The [XML::Simple docs say **not to use it in new code**](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE). This is a good example why. Instead, you can use [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig), which has extensive documentation.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
  twig_handlers => {
    'Location' => sub {
      my ( $twig, $elem ) = @_;
      say join ';', map { $elem->att($_) } qw( name square_feet highway );
    },
});

$twig->parse( \*DATA );

__DATA__
<Export land_name="tx">
<Area>
    <Location name="foo"
              square_feet="10,000"
              highway="I-35"/>
    <Location name="dog"
              square_feet="20,000"
              highway="I-45"/>
</Area>
</Export>
```

This defines a handler for the `<Location>` tag, and grabs the three attributes out of the tag. You can then do what you want with them.

Since you want to write them to a CSV file you can use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE). Set it up outside and call it to write stuff in the handler.

See also:

- [XML::Twig::Elt](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig#XML::Twig::Elt)

Comment: To make sure i can understand the code, you're making an object with XML::Twig->new
and setting the parameters to grab anything within the location tag, what is qw, and if I have a lot more attributes to work with do I have to list them all?

Comment: `qw( ... )` is the same as `split(' ', q( ... ))`

Comment: And yes, you will have to list them. How else are you going to make sure they're in the order you want?

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful that explanation is @ikegami. `qw` constructs a list from quoted words. It's identical to ('name', 'square_feet', 'highway').

Comment: You provided an explanation that works in one case. I provided an explanation that works in all cases. (Except I should have put the whole thing in parens.)

Comment: So I keep getting an error about "use" not being allowed in expression at the line (use XML::Twig ), but I'm not sure how that is creating an error. is there supposed to be a semicolon after (use feature 'say')?

Comment: Thanks so much for the help with this!

Answer (score 4):

XML::Simple:

```
# ForceArray => [qw( Location )],
# KeyAttr    => [],
# KeepRoot   => 1,

for my $node (@{ $doc->{Export}{Area}{Location} }) {
   say join ';',
      map { $node->{$_} }
         qw( name square_feet highway );
}
```

XML::Simple requires that you do all that configuration, and there are many gotchas. The module's own documentation advises you to avoid XML::Simple as a result.

XML::LibXML:

```
for my $node ($doc->findnodes('/Export/Area/Location')) {
   say join ';',
      map { $node->getAttribute($_) }
         qw( name square_feet highway );
}
```

XML::Twig:

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
   twig_handlers => {
      '/Export/Area/Location' => sub {
         my ($twig, $elem) = @_;
         say join ';',
            map { $elem->att($_) }
               qw( name square_feet highway );
      },
   },
);
```